# Exercise 1.14 in Brezis' Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

[image]

Hi, I am looking for guidance to solve exercise 1.14 of Brezis functional analysis textbook, see above.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? And if have multiple questions as in your exercise, could you please ask them separately? This increases the likelihood for you to get an answer.

Comment: Yes, actually, I have a particular question regarding part c. I saw an answer that stated that if there exists a linear functional such that it separates Y and Z, then that functional is not continuous. First I didn't understand why that functional is 0 both in X and Y, and furthermore why this means that the functional isn't zero everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The first point can be resolved in this way:

Let $\{\delta_n: \mathcal{l}^1\to \mathbb{R}\}_n$ the dual base of $\mathcal{l}^1$  in $(\mathcal{l}^1)^*$. Than

$X=\bigcap_n\delta_{2n}^{-1}(0)$

So X is a subspace of $\mathcal{l}^1$ because is the intersection of subspaces $\delta_{2n}^{-1}(0)$ and is closed because is the intersection of closed subsets of $\mathcal{l}^1$

In the dame way you can define for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the map $\alpha_n:=\delta_{2n}-\frac{1}{2^n}\delta_{2n-1}$ and so

$Y=\bigcap_n\alpha_n^{-1}(0)$

That is a closed subspace of $ l^1$

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\overline{X+Y} = E$ it suffices to find a sequence of elements in $X+Y$ that converges to an element $y = (0, y_{2}, 0, y_{4}, 0, y_{6}, \dots)\in E$. The $m^{\text{th}}$ term of such a sequence may be given by
\begin{equation*}
    (\dots, 0, \underbrace{\frac{y_{2n}}{2^{n}}\sum_{r = 0}^{m-1}\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\Big)^{r}}_{2n^{\text{th}}\text{ term}}, \dots). 
\end{equation*}
Check that the sequence is in $X+Y$. To show that this sequence converges to $y$ we need to show that
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|y_{2n}|\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\Big)^{m} = 0.
\end{equation*}
For this, let $N$ be large enough such that $\sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty}|y_{2n}| < \varepsilon/2$ and choose $M$ large enough such that for $m\geq M$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{n = 1}^{N}|y_{2n}|\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\Big)^{m} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
    \end{equation*}